# ImportError while installing lxml on OS X 10.6

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to install lxml on OS X 10.6 using Python 2.7a3. However I am receiving an error during the install setup: ImportError: cannot import name _config_vars

I have put the terminal output [here](http://pastebin.com/B9mEMNVD).

Thanks.

Comment: Note that 2.7a3 is an alpha release of Python 2.7, and considering it was followed by another alpha, two beta's, two release candidates and two patchreleases, you can expect it to have quite a lot of bugs that are fixed in, say, Python 2.7.2.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling macports, and downloading the 2.7.2 DMG and installing that way. I did have to figure out how to edit .bash_profile, however that was not very difficult. I think, at least in the beginning, it makes more sense to do all of it manually to understand what is happening and then later to move into using things like macports, pip, easy_install, etc. Anyway, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an alpha release of Python 2.7.0, an alpha release for which `setuptools`, which is used by lxml's `setup.py`, doesn't work. Setuptools relies on an implementation detail of `distutils.sysconfig` (the `_config_vars` attribute) that was changed in the early Python 2.7 alpha releases, and reverted later in the release process (to un-break setuptools, in all likelyhood.)

It's a good idea to install alpha releases to test if your own software works in the newer Python version, but you should not keep using them after newer versions are released, and certainly not after the final release has been made. In this case, two more patchreleases were made later; you should really install those instead.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was odd, but I ended up using macports and the newest version of Python 2.7 they had (and still do) is 2.7a3. I will try to remove it all together and just do it manually. Hopefully that should solve it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you've had a `10.7`, I'd ask "have you latest `X-Code` installed?", because I got no errors just now.
But instead I will ask: did you try/consider `easy_install` or `pip install`?

Comment: I tried easy_install, however that gave me a host of other errors.